# url scheme open view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, url-scheme

I have read multiple things on handling url schemes to open different view controllers within my app. I just cannot understand it. I have been following the tutorial from Twitter https://dev.twitter.com/cards/mobile/deep-linking however have removed  [self.viewController presentHomeScreen]; as Xcode gives the following error "Property 'viewController' not found on object of type ScanmarksAppDelegate".

I simply want to open a view controller (storyboard) named `ARViewController` when the url is scanmarks://scan     then open view controller (storyboard) named ScanmarksinfoTableViewController when the url is `scanmarks://about`

```
-(BOOL) application: (UIApplication * ) application openURL: (NSURL * ) url sourceApplication: (NSString * ) sourceApplication annotation: (id) annotation {
if ([url.scheme isEqualToString: @"scanmarks"]) {
    // check our `host` value to see what screen to display
    //TODO you can also pass parameters - e.g. birdland://home?refer=twitter
    if ([url.host isEqualToString: @"scan"]) {

    } else if ([url.host isEqualToString: @"about"]) {

    } else {
        NSLog(@"An unknown action was passed.");
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"We were not opened with scanmarks.");
}
return NO;
}
```

Comment: The code seems fine, you just have to add your own presentXXXScreen functions (eg to your root view controller and call them from your app delegate, like the tutorial does)

Comment: Implementation of the presenting methods and the place where you want to implement them depends on how you want to present the new controllers. The key window might be enough, you can get it from the shared application delegate instance. If any presented view controller is good for you, then a root window's controller should suffice. If there's a need for a specific controller reference, you'll need to get a direct reference to it or implement notifications or delegates chain to get to it. There's a lot of options and decisions depend on what you need to do, try to follow the tutorial exactly.